# How to make a new list from a list which is 3/4th the size of the original one in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

Ex. I have a list

```
LIST=[1,2,3,3,4,4,5,9]
```

Now, I want to create a list which is 3/4th of this list

```
[1,2,3,3,4,4]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
LIST[:int(len(LIST) * 0.75)]
```